# field Type no passing tag data to replace_tag function

Tags: fieldtype

having a bit of a problem with a field type and trying to pass in tag data.:

in my template i have

```
{entries ...} {field} {keys}{key}{/keys}{/field} {/entries}
```

however when i do a `var_dump($tag_data)` in the `replace_tag()` function i am getting false.

however a `var_dump($data)` if producing the expected data in the same function..

Any Ideas?

Additional:
i have already tried a tag pair in the same format as

`{myfield:option}
    Tag data here
{/myfield}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the [`has_array_data`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#EE_Fieldtype%3a%3a%24has_array_data) property to your fieldtype class:

```
class My_field extends EE_Fieldtype {
  public $has_array_data = TRUE;

  ...
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply - could you eleborate on how to do that - this is my first time creating a field type and the docs are lacking..

Comment: Updated the example. It's really that simple.

Comment: most excellent - kinda makes a mockery of my wasted time though  hehe